# Incrementing a field in SQL using PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have a table (T1) with some fields F2, F3 (Columns) with already some values in it .... .

I need to add a new field (F1) to the table (T1) and F1 will be the primary key .

The field type F1 is a integer .

I assigned a random 8 digit number to the first row of F1 and the remaining rows should be incremented by 1 from the previous row. This increment should go in par with the other fields F2 , F3 etc...

This F1 should also be increased if entirely new row is added to the table.

I tried to do it with lastinsertid() in PHP but it only works for rows which are newly created.

Can u ppl help me in writing the code for the above using lastinsertid().

If its not clear plzz let me know..

Comment: Would it not be easier to set `F1` as an auto-incrementing integer? Then it will increment every time a new row is added automatically.

Comment: I'd like to help you, but it's not really clear to me what you mean. You have an existing Table with 2 columns and you want to add a new column to that?? If you set your F1 to auto_increment, it will automatically add 1 to the id of the previous row. So you can just INSERT (F2, F3) VALUES ('val1', 'val2'); and F1 will automatically be assigned.

Comment: Well i need to only use the function lastInsertId function in PHP.. what lastinsertid does is that Returns the ID of the last inserted row or sequence value ..

Comment: @razzz manzzz - Assuming you're using MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using MySQL:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable
AUTO_INCREMENT = 1677216 ,
ADD COLUMN F1 INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT ;
```

Existing rows will have the  `F1` field automatically filled with ids, starting from `1677216`.

---

If you are worried that it is an integer and not a string, pretend it's a string by never using `id`, only use `RIGHT(id,8)`