# Incrementing a field in a SQL table using PHP

Tags: php, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Incrementing a field in SQL using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589833/incrementing-a-field-in-sql-using-php)

I have a table (T1) with some fields F2, F3 (Columns) with already some values in it .... .

I need to add a new field (F1) to the table (T1) and F1 will be the primary key .

The field type F1 is a integer .

I assigned a random 8 digit number to the first row of F1 and the remaining rows should be incremented by 1 from the previous row. This increment should go in par with the other fields F2 , F3 etc...

This F1 should also be increased if entirely new row is added to the table.

I tried to do it with lastinsertid() in PHP but it only works for rows which are newly created.

Can u ppl help me in writing the code for the above using lastinsertid().

If its not clear plzz let me know..

Comment: Have you tried an `auto_increment`ing `PRIMARY KEY`?

Comment: Nope i just want to increase the next field by checking previous field using lastinsertid() .

Comment: For what database?  Using the databases' native functionality is a much better idea -- there's no way to ensure PHP wouldn't attempt to insert a duplicate without experiencing an error.

Comment: @zerkms : i made few changes after few hrs ..so the changed question is not answered there..its not exactly a duplicate..

Comment: Come on, the question is an ***exact duplicate***. Copied and pasted. At least specify why the answer doesn't apply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the `primary key` of your table to `auto_increment`. Check [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) for more info